# move index.php to another directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver, query-string

I am using this GitHub page: https://github.com/Athlon1600/php-proxy-app and as it's supposed to, when I go to [development.stech.software](http://development.stech.software) it loads up `index.php`.

When I choose a link, it makes it a query string like this [development.stech.software/index.php?q=y6ml06abkWPdp6pnn6PVl6TLlMSkpmdvzdzUj6WZbqbWoQ](http://development.stech.software/index.php?q=y6ml06abkWPdp6pnn6PVl6TLlMSkpmdvzdzUj6WZbqbWoQ) (where the random characters is the query).

How do I adjust the `index.php` file, so that when I go to a URL, it loads it on `/index.php/query/y6ml06abkWPdp6pnn6PVl6TLlMSkpmdvzdzUj6WZbqbWoQ` or something similar.

I tried this, but it wouldn't work (it reported 500), I found it from [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

```
$path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');    // Trim leading slash(es)
$elements = explode('/', $path);                // Split path on slashes
if(empty($elements[0])) {                       // No path elements means home
    ShowHomepage();
} else switch(array_shift($elements))             // Pop off first item and switch
{
    case 'index':
        ShowPicture($elements); // passes rest of parameters to internal function
        break;
    case 'more':
        ...
    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        Show404Error();
}
```

I also added this to .htaccess `FallbackResource htdocs/index.php`

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: i've tried a lot of different things with .htaccess to do what I want, but it didn't work. that's why i'm trying it with php now. i've edited the question to show what i used. @starkeen

Answer (score 0):

To redirect `/index.php?q=foobar` to `/index.php/query/foobar` you can use the following Rule in your htaccess file:

```
 FallbackResource htdocs/index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index.php/query/%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: How can I remove the .php, so that I can remove password protection for the query sub directory. Right now the link is [https://development.stech.software/index.php/query/index.php?q=QUERY], and my goal is to password protect access to index.php, but allow access to query. @starkeen

Comment: Please don't use the comment sections to ask additional questions. Instead you should vote up good answers and hit the accept button if the *original question* has been answered.